# How can I get an Int from the tuple in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell, and currently looking for a way to extract or delete the first `Int` in a tuple. Is there a built-in Haskell function to do that? 
For instance:

```
tuple :: (Int)
tuple = (1,2,3,4,5)

tuple !! 0 =
```

Comment: You can not do this because values are immutable.  You have declared `tuple` equals `(1,2,3,4,5)` and it will forever be so.  Notice your type is wrong, it should actually be `tuple :: (Int,Int,Int,Int,Int)`.  If you wanted a list then that's different.

Comment: But can I extract them ? Create a variable which will be equal the first element of the Tuple?

Comment: Sure, pattern matching is your friend here. Large tuples are typically avoided since they're clumsy and rather generic when a data declaration is usually appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As defined in the OP, the type of `tuple` is this:

```
Prelude> tuple = (1,2,3,4,5)
Prelude> :t tuple
tuple
  :: (Num t4, Num t3, Num t2, Num t1, Num t) => (t4, t3, t2, t1, t)
```

There's no type `(Int)`. Instead, the type is `(t4, t3, t2, t1, t)`, where each of those five types has to be a `Num` instance. There's more than a single type to chose from, and since all five types can vary independently of each other, the type *could* be `(Int, Word, Float, Integer, Int)`.

The reason for this is that each literal in the definition (`1`, `2`, etc.) could be interpreted as any of those types, and when you write an expression like that, the compiler keeps your options open.

If you want it to be a tuple exclusively made up of `Int` values, you can declare that:

```
tuple :: (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int)
tuple = (1,2,3,4,5)
```

If you want the first element of the tuple, you can use *pattern matching* to extract that information:

```
Prelude> (x, _, _, _, _) = tuple
Prelude> x
1
```

The above expression uses *wildcards* to ignore the other four elements of the tuple, but if you need one or more of those, you can bind to named values as well:

```
Prelude> (x, _, z, _, _) = tuple
Prelude> z
3
```

As Thomas M. DuBuisson points out in a comment to the OP, however, you'd probably be better off with other language constructs than large tuples.

If I may venture a guess, I suppose the OP is actually about *lists*, not tuples. Certain languages (particularly dynamic languages) don't make much of a distinction between lists and tuples. This makes some sense in a dynamic language where types are unknown at compile-time.

Haskell, however, is a statically typed language, and lists and tuples are different.

- A tuple is a data structure with a fixed length, but where you can flexibly choose the type of each individual element.
- A list is a data structure with a fixed element type, but where you can vary the length.

Perhaps you're looking for a list of integers:

```
list :: [Int]
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Given such a list, you can, for instance, use the `!!` operator to extract the first element:

```
Prelude> list !! 0
1
```

Do note, however, that `!!` is unsafe, because if you give it an out-of-range index, it's going to throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it's really useful.  However, I need to create a function which takes a tuple with 4 integers . I would love to use lists but I can't :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) library:

```
tuple :: (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int)
tuple = (1,2,3,4,5)

secondElement = tuple ^. _2 -- One indexed
```

For tuples with exactly 2 elements you can use `fst` and `snd` from Prelude to get the first and second element respectively